# restrict access to ssh by hostname with iptables

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

I want to allow connecting via ssh only for a certain domain sub.example.com. How can I do this via iptables?

Comment: You need your machine to receive connections only from `sub.domain.com`, or you want your machine to only be able to connect to `sub.domain.com`?

Comment: The second. I want to access to connect to me only on sub.domail.com.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `iptables` works only with IP addresses - if you pass it a name, it will do a lookup and convert it to an IP before adding that rule. On output, it will (unless `-n` is specified) do lookups and give you hostnames for all IPs it can reverse resolve. To operate on domains, you must use an alternative solution such as `hosts.deny`.

Comment: As I understand it: I must add `sshd:ALL` to hosts.deny and `sshd:sub.example.com` to hosts.allow?